# Fixed wrong output that has been written in a code comment - edit got rejected

Tags: discussion, support

I fixed the wrong output in a code comment that was clearly wrong and misleading. It's the top and approved answer and obviously he only copied the code from the question and then changed the code without adjusting the comment with the output. It's very confusing if a comment states a different output than the code does, I think it's legitimate to fix that.

I edited that and fixed it. 2 declined my edit, 1 approved it. It got declined. What to do in those cases? Honestly, it's pretty annoying if users fix wrong stuff and then the edit gets rejected.

And leaving a comment on the answer that has obviously a mistake included? That's not a good solution imo.

Here the links:

Rejected edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23090043

Question: [Get a PHP DateTime difference in days, considering midnight as a day change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102603/get-a-php-datetime-difference-in-days-considering-midnight-as-a-day-change/18102701#18102701)

Comment: Thanks @yivi for editing it and fixing the wrong output.

Comment: I just realised after 2,000 reputation (not far away from that) my edits get approved automatically. But the basic problem remains - legitimate edits being refused for no good reason is imo not good.

Comment: Only ~70Rep and you will have the power to edit the world. Gambate.

Comment: Reviewers will review. Some of them correctly, others less so. What do you expect meta to do about this? In general, suggested edits to code are always a risky business. Luckly in about 60 points you won't be subject to review anymore.

Comment: Edits to code are a touchy subject, people will see that as a form of trespassing. *Don't touch someone else's code; if you can do better, post your own answer with your own code and be judged for it on your own reputation pool.* Sometimes there is merit to that too, but not in this particular case of course.

Comment: Your edit was fine and a perfect use of the edit privilege. Your edit description was not bad either. But suggesting changes to code, even if these changes are to _comments_, is not always a great experience when your edits need to be reviewed and reviewers may not be subject matter expects to judge the validity of your edits. Better to apply them when you have full edit privileges.

Comment: Of course, I totally understand that. But I even posted a link to the code execution so the reviewer can verify the output. It's just frustrating if reviewers do a bad job. My experience with reviews hasn't been very good here in general, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, I checked some of your latest rejected suggestions, and I have to say I find merit in those rejections. Neither [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12146474), nor [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12147120), nor [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12371610) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12360523) are good edits. So maybe your experience wasn't so bad as you think it was. Just got a dud with this latest experience. These edits are generally very old, so very likely you'd do better today.